# Make decimal point to whole numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, double, decimal

I have textBox1 and it contains number 10. I need to get that number 10 to double with decimal point. My current code is:

```
variables.myNum = double.Parse(textBox1);
```

I have declared myNum in variables class:

```
public static double myNum;
```

With that code I get that number 10 to double. The problem is that I need to have decimal point too so I would like to have "10.". If I write to textBox1 "10." it doesn't work.

EDIT: .ToString("0.00") gives the decimal point to whole numbers but it also gives those two zeros which I do not want. Only point is needed with whole numbers.

EDIT: First I have:

```
10
10.5
10.58
10.589
```

I would like to have: (note dot after 1st ten)

```
10.
10.5
10.58
10.589
```

With .ToString("0.00") I can get:

```
10.00
10.50
10.58
10.58
```

But I don't want those extra zeros at the end. Only dot and numbers which are not zero.

Comment: There's no such concept as "double with a decimal point" - it's just a number. When are you *using* `myNum`? You should basically format it how you want it when you convert it to a string.

Comment: Your SO profile does not say what country you live in.  That's important when you ask a question like this.  Try using a comma instead of a decimal period.  If you insist on using a period then you must pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat to the Parse() method.

Comment: I'm using myNum in string[] lines ={...}. Can I convert it in there somehow? I want to use period instead comma. I have set CultureInfo so that makes period over comma.

Comment: If all you want is a number with a `.` after it, then you can just round the decimal appropriately, convert to a string and concatenate a `.` on to the end. But I can't think of why that would be useful - I would be interested in _why_ you are doing it.

Comment: I'm doing a G-code generator. In G-code there must be a decimal point in every number. If I make dot after every number then decimal numbers have two decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `.`, if the output doesn't contain one already.

```
public static string ToGCodeNumber(double number, int digits)
{
    // rounding (optional)
    double number = Math.Round(number, digits);

    // result with or without '.'
    string intermediateResult = roundedNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if(!intermediateResult.Contains(".")
        intermediateResult += ".";

    // final result with a guaranteed '.'  
    return intermediateResult;
}
```

Comment: Your code has an error in 'return'. It seems that function tries to return void.

Answer (score -4):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Test1());
    Console.WriteLine(Test2());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static decimal Test1()
{
    return 10.999999999999999999999M;
}
static decimal Test2()
{
    return (decimal)10.999999999999999999999;
}
```

The first returns 10.999999999999999999999 but the seccond returns 11